# Dojo does not parse widget declarative in a template html of a custom widget

Tags: javascript, dojo

Dojo not seem to parse widget declaratively created in a template html file of a custom widget.

But it works when I am declaratively create it in the home page where dojo configuration was done

here is the code snippet:

*Home page:*

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var dojoConfig = {
            parseOnLoad: true,
            isDebug: true,
            modulePaths : {"com.cgb":"../../../client/vtm/com/cgb"}
};
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../common/dojo/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    dojo.require("dojo.parser");
    dojo.require("com.cgb.modules.deposit.step1_agreement");
    dojo.require("dojox.mobile.ScrollableView");
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div data-dojo-type="com.cgb.modules.deposit.step1_agreement"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

*the custom widget:*

```
dojo.provide("com.cgb.modules.deposit.step1_agreement");

dojo.require("dojo.cache");
dojo.require("dijit._Widget");
dojo.require("dijit._Templated");

dojo.require("dojox.mobile.ScrollableView");

dojo.declare("com.cgb.modules.deposit.step1_agreement", [dijit._Widget, dijit._Templated], {
    templateString: dojo.cache("com.cgb.modules.deposit", "templates/step1_agreement.html"),
    postCreate:function(){
        console.log("widget get instantiated");
    }
});
```

*template html of the custom  widget:*

```
<div>
    <!--this widget didn't get parsed -->
    <div id="view1" dojoType="dojox.mobile.ScrollableView" height="50px">
        blah blahblah blah<br/>blah blahblah blah<br/>blah blahblah blah<br/>
        blah blahblah blah<br/>blah blahblah blah<br/>blah blahblah blah<br/>
        blah blahblah blah<br/>blah blahblah blah<br/>blah blahblah blah<br/>
    </div>
</div>
```

the ScrollableView widget didn't get parsed, but when I declare it at the Home page it works. I think maybe I must miss something, please help me out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since youre using dojox.mobile, youre probably in-between syntaxes with your code..

http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.7/modules/#Defining_modules

For future versions, where u use widgets in the template, the parameter `widgetsInTemplate: true` gets deprecated. In turn, include the `dijit._WidgetsInTemplateMixin` as a mixin of your module.

e.g; **< 1.7**

```
dojo.provide("com.cgb.modules.deposit.step1_agreement");
dojo.require("...");
dojo.declare("com.cgb.modules.deposit.step1_agreement", [dijit._Widget, dijit._Templated], {


    widgetsInTemplate: true,


    templateString: dojo.cache("com.cgb.modules.deposit", "templates/step1_agreement.html"),
    postCreate:function(){
        console.log("widget get instantiated");
    }
});
```

and **1.7+** ( expects module to have filename/path as module and namespace )

```
define([ "dojo/_base/declare", "dijit/_WidgetBase", "dijit/_TemplatedMixin", 

        "dijit/_WidgetsInTemplateMixin" ], // note latter mixin

    function(declare, _WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin){
       return declare([ _WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin ], {});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer at this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131814/dijit-combobox-not-rendering-in-custom-widget?rq=1).

I missed **`widgetsInTemplate: true`** in my widget declaration.

Comment: Note that the need to set `widgetsInTemplate` is only an issue if you are using dojo versions 1.6 or 1.7. Dojo 1.8 or 1.9 no longer requires you to set this attribute, I guess someone decided that the fact you choose to mixin `dijit/_WidgetsInTemplateMixin` (as was pointed out by mschr) module is statement enough that you will want to have child widgets within your template.